# Find $\sin(\frac{x}{2})$, given $\tan(x) = 2$, with $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find $\sin(\frac{x}{2})$, given $\tan(x) = 2$, with $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Which half-identity formular should I use and why?

Comment: Use the one that relates $\sin(x/2)$ to $\cos x$. Then all you have to do is get $\cos x$ from knowing $\tan x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\tan^2 x + 1 =\sec^2 x\\
\sec x = \sqrt 5\\
\cos x = \frac {1}{\sqrt 5}\\
\sin \frac{x}{2} = \sqrt {\frac {1-\cos x}{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac1{\cos x}=\sec x=+\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}$$

Now $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y$

Here $\sin\dfrac x2>0$ right?

Comment: the question doesn't say. probably

Comment: @Evelyn, It definitely does, but not directly. Why $\cos x>0?$